# Why we want to prove the facts that the coefficients of a polynomial with real negative roots are log-concave functions of the roots.

Tags: polynomials, convex-optimization

From Convex Optimization, Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vandenberghe, page 123 exercise 3.50, I know that the coefficients of a polynomial with real negative roots are log-concave functions of the roots. We can have this result by proving $e_r(a)^{1/r}$ is concave on $\textbf{R}_{+}^{n}$, where $e_{r}(a)$ is the $r$-th elementary symmetric function.

I want to know the reason why we want to prove this fact. I found that some articles about roots of polynomial, they also discussing about the log-concavity of coefficients (sequence) of polynomials. However, they discussing the log-concavity of sequence, e.g. coefficients of polynomials, but not the log-concavity of coefficient of
polynomial with real negative roots itself is a log-concave functions of its roots. Maybe there are some relations between these two things, hope someone can give me some helps.